# Silverlight DataPager breaks VS designer

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm experimenting with the Silverlight 4 SDK DataPager.  I have some code in my XAML that looks like this:

```
        <sdk:DataPager 
            x:Name="dataPager1"
            PageSize="100" />
```

As SOON as I paste that into my XAML the designer breaks with this odd message:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

But if I close the designer and re-open then that error goes away.  However, the preview in the designer of my user control is completely broken.  At runtime it works though.

Any idea why the DataPager and the designer don't seem to be getting along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough when I tried this again in a new project it did not happen.  In the first project where I got this error I manually created the XAML and the references to the DLLs necessary, as well as the XMLNS declarations.  In the second project I let Visual Studio take care of it by dragging the control in from the Toolbox.  I guess when I did things manually I must've done something to make it not work right in the designer.  But I don't know what.